# Setting new data-context doesn't change

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm, mvvm-light

In my project I have something like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyObservableCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <View:MyView DataContext="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

`MyView` of course has the data-binding to the locator, as usual in MVVM-Light:

```
DataContext="{Binding MyViewModelLocatorProperty, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
```

`ItemsControl` has correctly created instances of `MyView`, but it did **not** appear to set the data-context (the data-context changed event was even raised). I've been struggling all day to find the problem & fix it and I've realized that the issue was those two data-context sets.

The way to fix this issue was to remove the data-context from `MyView`'s XAML, but that's an ugly fix and it also means no blendability whatsoever. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: remove the converter. Actually remove the `DataContext` binding entirely. It's redundant.

Comment: @HighCore Okay, do you have an answer tho?

Comment: Yes, my answer is: `remove the converter. Actually remove the DataContext binding entirely. It's redundant.`. About blendability: use `d:DataContext` for design time. Remove the hard coded DataContext

Comment: @HighCore I'll try it but can you explain why would that fix my problem?

Comment: Because you're using a converter where it does not belong. an ItemsControl will automatically assign the corresponding item as the `DataContext` of each UI item.

Comment: @HighCore Oh I didn't know that. But that doesn't solve the problem (just tried it). The data-binding in the view still appears to override the data-context set in the `ItemsControl`.

Comment: Once again, REMOVE the hard coded `DataContext`. Use `d:DataContext` if you need design time data. The "ViewModelLocator" concept (whatever it is and however it works) is clearly not intended to be used for ItemsControl's Data Items.

Comment: @HighCore Oh I'm sorry, I thought you talked about the data-context in the `ItemsControl`, excuse me for being a little slow. So if I do this, how can I instantiate new views without an existing view-model?

Comment: The ItemsControl will take care of that.

Comment: @HighCore When it has a collection. Again, I'm talking about when it's doesn't have an existing view-model, i.e. when I just have `<ViewMyView />` in my window.

Comment: In that case (outside the ItemsControl) you will want to set the datacontext, `<MyView DataContext="{Binding Something}"/>`, but not when inside `ItemsControl`.

Comment: @HighCore Oh, thought so (specifically to use the locator property there) but wanted to verify it's good practice because it seems repetitive, but okay. Thanks a lot for your help, the answer was to use `d:DataContext`. Feel free to write it as an answer so I could accept it.